# put last 3 non NAs from each column into list while maintaining columns

Tags: r

I've got a df1 like this:

```
Date <-c("12/10/17","12/11/17","12/12/17","12/13/17","12/14/17","12/15/17","12/16/17")
Ben <- c(1294,NA,8959,2345,NA,0303,NA)
James <- c(NA,4523,3246,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Alex <- c(3754,1122,5582,NA,2910,NA,NA)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Ben,James,Alex)`

#df1
Date          Ben     James     Alex
12/10/17      1294    NA        3754
12/11/17      NA      4523      1122
12/12/17      8959    3246      5582
12/13/17      2345    NA        NA
12/14/17      NA      NA        2910
12/15/17      0303    NA      NA
12/16/17      NA      NA      NA
```

I'd like to get a list that takes the last 3 non NA values from each column and maintains their columns. If there are less than 3 non NA values in the column, it lists what is there, so columns may be of unequal lengths:

```
Ben     James     Alex
8959    4523      1122
2345    3246      5582
0303              2910
```

This gets the last 3, but puts them all in one uncategorized vector:

```
c(sapply(df[-1], function(x) sprintf("%s", tail(x[!is.na(x)], 3))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you mean by *"puts them all in one uncategorized vector"*. Doesn't this do what you want?

```
lapply(df1[-1], function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], n = 3))
#$Ben
#[1] 8959 2345  303
#
#$James
#[1] 4523 3246
#
#$Alex
#[1] 1122 5582 2910
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = c(sapply(df1[-1], function(x) sprintf("%s", tail(x[!is.na(x)], 3))))

out = as.data.frame(t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(temp, t))))
colnames(out) = colnames(df1[-1])
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want them in one vector?

```
Date <-c("12/10/17","12/11/17","12/12/17","12/13/17","12/14/17","12/15/17","12/16/17")
Ben <- c(1294,NA,8959,2345,NA,0303,NA)
James <- c(NA,4523,3246,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Alex <- c(3754,1122,5582,NA,2910,NA,NA)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Ben,James,Alex)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  map(~tail(na.omit(.x), 3)) %>% 
  flatten_dbl()
```

Produces

```
[1] 8959 2345  303 4523 3246 1122 5582 2910
```